# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. How to Find out 1 and 0 count from 4D array

Tags: python

I'm calculating a segmentation evaluation work where I have prediction and ground truth. Both predicted array and ground truth array shape (28, 1, 224, 224). Now to calculate True positive (TP), True Negative (TN), False positive (FP), False Negative (FN). I used to calculate these values using this code given bellow But got some error.

```
def perf_measure( y_hat , y_actual):
TP = 0
FP = 0
TN = 0
FN = 0


for i in range(len(y_hat)): 
    
    if y_actual[i]==1 and y_hat[i]==1:
       TP += 1
    if y_hat[i]==1 and y_actual[i]!=y_hat[i]:
       FP += 1
    if y_actual[i]==0 and y_hat[i]==0:
       TN += 1
    if y_hat[i]==0 and y_actual[i]!=y_hat[i]:
       FN += 1

return(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Maybe Your y_hat is an array for single prediction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is 4 dimensional, then you need to iterate through all dimensions. But there is a better solution: reshape you arrays using `y_hat.flatten()` and `y_true.flatten()` and run them through a [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html). See the example in the confusion matrix description on how to get TP, FP, TN, FN all at once.